# Listado de todas las entradas en wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Actualmente estoy desarrollando un tema para Wordpress. En el inicio hay una sección donde aparece noticias destacadas y últimas noticias. Las noticias destacadas se determinan dependiendo de una etiqueta y en las últimas noticias se muestran las 3 últimas entradas publicadas en wordpress. ¿Cómo puedo agregar un link que diga todas las noticias y me redirija a una página que muestre todas las noticias? Gracias de antemano

Este sería el home.php de mi tema donde aparecen las 3 últimas noticias o entradas. En la sección de abajo está `más noticias`.
[image: Ejemplo]

Comment: Hola. Dinis qué has investigado y muéstranos qué has intentado y qué errores/problemas tienes para poder ayudarte. Hay varias formas de hacer lo que quieres y debemos al menos saber qué forma concreta has elegido... Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: @A.Cedano es que no se que hacer, he buscado pero no he encontrado una solución

Comment: Puedes hacer esto fácilmente con un `shortcode` por ejemplo, o insertando *hooks*  en la plantilla de tu tema. Son sólo dos formas posibles que se me ocurren (podría haber más). Por eso es necesario tener un punto de partida desde el cual poder ayudarte. Investiga un poco sobre *shortcode*, intenta con eso y si tienes algún error o problema te ayudaremos. Es casi imposible responder a una pregunta partiendo desde cero, porque debes indicarnos sobre qué estás trabajando en concreto, no podemos nosotros recrear tu contexto.

Comment: He visto que con `shortcode` se crea en el `functions.php` y después se crea una página con ese `shortcode` y se muestra pero no me parece la solución más óptima. Usando hooks no sabría decirte

Comment: [`get_post_type_archive_link( 'post' );`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type_archive_link/) donde `post` es el post_type

Comment: ¿Por qué no te parece la solución más óptima? Si investigas cómo funciona luego vas a alucinar. Hablamos de que poniendo simplemente algo como esto: `[listallposts]` podrías obtener una lista de todas las entradas. O poniendo algo como: `[listbycategory param="news"]` obtendrías una lista de todos los posts de la categoría `news`. Claro que hay que programar una función de 4 ó 5 líneas en `functions.php`, algo ínfimo comparado con las amplias posibilidades que te da el uso de shortcodes, de hecho, Wordpress los usa de forma nativa, por ejemplo para los `[caption]` y otras cosas.

Comment: @aloMalbarez yo pondría esa línea en mi `home.php` y entonces crearía un `archive.php` donde mostraría todas entradas (foor loop)?

Comment: @A.Cedano no me parece la mejor opción ya que habría que hacerlo desde la administración y es algo que se puede generar automáticamente para el usuario final

Comment: @ReinierHernándezÁvila si el `archive.php` general no lo provee el theme parent/child wp toma el `index.php` haciendo el loop tradicional, si queres customizar un archive para un post type en particular podes copiar `index.php`  o `archive.php` como `archive-slugdelpostype.php` hay una guia visual de como wp busca los php en https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/Screenshot-2019-01-23-00.20.04.png

Comment: No es así, no hay que hacer nada desde la administración, si programas un shorcode, él hará lo que hayas pedido donde quieras que pongas ese shortcode, sea en una página, en un post, etc. Así, cuando crees la página o post basta con poner algo así por ejemplo: `[listbycategory param="news"]` y el shortcode pondrá en esa página o post una lista de los posts de la categoría `news` (es un ejemplo solamente).